# Is \$V_A\$ or \$V_B\$ the inverting input here?

Tags: differential, current-mirror

[image]
Is \$V_A\$ or \$V_B\$ the inverting input and why?

Comment: I'm going to guess the reason for your down-vote is that you are linking to an image that can disappear at any time rather than either copying that image here *or* re-creating it here.

Comment: In other words, please post the image here.

Comment: @DwayneReid - I have edited it for the chap, it was linked through stackexchange's imgur page.

Answer (score 7):

Pick one of the inputs and follow the signal to the output.  This is easy and the result obvious if you understand the basics of how transistors work in a circuit.  If not, then that's what you should be asking about before trying to learn complete circuits.

When Va goes up, T1 takes more of the fixed Ibias current from T2.  In other words the current thru T1 increases.  The gate of M3 must be brought lower to allow this current to flow.  This lowers the gate of M4, which increases the current thru it, which increases the current thru R, which raises the output voltage.  From the Vout result for the Va input, it is now obvious whether Va is the inverting or non-inverting input.

From the comments I see there is confusion about basic transistor operation.  The gate of M3 must go lower to increase the current thru M3 because that's how P channel FETs work.  That is also the polarity assumed by how M3 is connected to T1.

Comment: So when Vb goes up, T2 takes more current and T1 takes less current, there's less current through R and V_out goes down? So, V_b is inverting?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to figure out what the circuit is doing, provided you understand some the basics about transistor theory.  I'm not going to spoon-feed you the answer but I'll provide guidance.

T1 & T2 are connected in what fashion?  The easy way to think of this is: which is the input terminal and where is the output signal coming from?  There are 3 common methods for connecting input and output signals to a single transistor and each of those methods has different characteristics.

M4 is similar to T1 or T2 in that there are 3 common methods for connecting input and output signals.

Come back and modify your question as needed if you require more help or explanation

[Edit]

There are 3 common methods of connecting signals to a transistor.  These are:

- Input to base, output from collector
- Input to base, output from emitter
- Input to emitter, output from collector

Each of these has different characteristics regarding input impedance, output impedance, voltage gain, current gain, signal inversion.

You can't analyse circuits until you understand the differences.

[Edit 2]

Olin Lathrop pointed out that I messed up regarding my description of M3.  I had said that it was a constant-current source - he pointed out that it is actually part of a current mirror formed by M3 & M4.

He is correct.

As the current through M3 increases, the current through M4 also increases.

Comment: I don't see how you relate the Common Base, Collector, Emitter impedances to this.... If V_A goes up T1 becomes more conductive, more current through the drain of M3, which mirrors through as more current through the drain of M4 and R and V_out goes up??? If V_b goes up, then more of the fixed bias current through T2 and less current through the collector of T1, M3 mirrored through M4 and R and V_out goes down????

Comment: No, M3 is not a constant current source.  The sum of the current thru T1 and T2 is Ibias.  The difference between the two inputs changes the fraction of Ibias carried by each T1 and T2.  The current thru M3 follows whatever T1 is doing.  M3 is essentially a feedback system that functions as a output current to input base voltage converter.  This base voltage is then fed to M4 to reconstruct this current thru M4 and R.  In other words, M3 and M4 are a *current mirror*.

Comment: @OlinLathrop So did I get it right?